# code that allows to input score of five students but how to add the score of all the students

Tags: python, class

I am a newbie who just learnt about functions and classes. I created a code using Class with a while loop that allows the entry of marks of five students in four subjects. Now I don't know how to add up the avg scores of all students and find the overall average score of the five students combined. I am providing the full code here. Please suggest all the improvements and solution to the problem.

```
entry = 1
while entry <=5:
    class Marks():
            def __init__(self, name, english_marks, hindi_marks, science_marks, economics_marks):
                self.name = name
                self.english_marks = english_marks
                self.hindi_marks = hindi_marks
                self.science_marks = science_marks
                self.economics_marks = economics_marks
            def output(self):
                print("\n")
                print("Hi "+self.name.title())
                avg_marks = (self.english_marks + self.hindi_marks + self.science_marks + self.economics_marks)/4
                print("Your average score is ", avg_marks)
                print("\n")
        
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    english_marks = int(input("Enter your English score: "))
    hindi_marks = int(input("Enter your Hindi score: "))
    science_marks = int(input("Enter your science score: "))
    economics_marks = int(input("Enter your economics score: "))
        
    j = Marks(name, english_marks, hindi_marks, science_marks, economics_marks)
    j.output()
    entry = entry + 1
```

Comment: One easy way is to just define an empty list, and append each students average score per iteration to it. In the end just do something like `all_avg = sum(name_of_list)/5` (replace 5 by number of students), also might have to format the result for decimals/significant numbers.

Comment: Defining a class in a loop is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you @JackTheCrab. The appending to an empty list solved my problem. Although even in that I had to struggle for some time. Now I have finally been able to use data from multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

## updated

Use the average values from each student to make a variable that averages the values
(you can make the five avg_marks variables in the output function based on what your entry value is.)

### example:

```
total =(avg_marks1+avg_marks2+avg_marks3+avg_marks4+avg_marks5)/5
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question on "*how to how to add up the avg scores of all students and find the overall average score of the five students combined*", exactly?

Comment: does this help?

Comment: No - you've still missed the point of the initial question. OP is collecting data for 5 "students" through 5 iterations of the loop - the question isn't asking about averaging across one of these students, as you've attempted to provide a solution to here. What they're asking about is how to average the scores across each of the `Marks` objects.

Comment: This should suffice